# What are all of the named locations?

Tags: achievements, borderlands-2

Several achievements require visiting every "named location":
[image: achievements]

What are the named locations in Three Horns, Tundra Express, Frostburn Canyon, Sanctuary, Opportunity, Lynchwood, The Highlands, Thousand Cuts, Wildlife Exploitation Preserve, Eridium Blight, Arid Nexus, Sawtooth Cauldron, and any other places required for their five achievements ("Arctic Explorer", "Urban Explorer", "Highlands Explorer", "Blight Explorer", and "World Traveler")?

Are any easy to miss? Which? Is there any way to easily identify remaining named locations?

Answer (score 7):

Here is the list of places for "World Traveler". I did not include the other locations for the other 4 achievements as those would be included to get this achievement.
Hope this helps.

**Windshear Waste**

- Claptrap's Place
- Frostbite Crevasse

**Southern Shelf**

- Liar's Berg
- Gateway Harbor
- Wreck of the Ice Sickle
- The Soaring Dragon
- Bandit Freighter

**Southern Shelf Bay**

- Ice Flows
- Ebonfloe
- Blackburn Cove

**Southpaw Steam & Power**

- None

**The Dust**

- Boot Hill
- Ellie's Garage
- Old Dahlwell Oasis
- Bug Gulch
- Moonshiner's Shack
- Goose's Roost
- Hodunk Speedway

**Bloodshot Stronghold**

- Rat's Nest
- Satan's Suckhole

**Bloodshot Ramparts**

- Shrine of the Gunbringer

**Friendship Gulag**

- None

**End of the Line**

- Snowblind Defile
- Terminus Plateau

**The Fridge**

- The Rat Maze
- Crystal Claw Pit
- Frigid Cleft
- The Rakk Cave
- Icemaw Grotto
- Stalker Hollow

**Fink's Slaughterhouse**

- Fink's Slaughter Factory

**The Holy Spirits**

- Ale Wee Cavern

**Caustic Caverns**

- Oozing Discharge
- Dahl Deep Core 06
- Rumbling Shore
- Nether Hive
- Varkid Ramparts
- Abandoned Mining Site
- Infested Warehouse
- Guardian Ruins

**The Bunker**

- None

**Control Core Angel**

- None

**Marcus's Munitions Storeroom**

- None

**Ore Chasm**

- None

**Hero's Pass**

- Guardian Slag Heap
- Emergency Supply Cache
- Drift Mouth Access

**Vault of the Warrior**

- None

**Terramorphous Peak (Not Required)**

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the names of the locations and honestly it doesn't matter, all that matters is completely filling out the map to every one of those areas. Go there and check your map, if any of it is blank or if there are any areas where the map outline disappears and then starts again go there and hopefully the blank spot will be filled into a named location as you go there. Also bear in mind that certain areas like Three Horns and The Highlands are actually split into two seperate areas divided by a travel marker.

Source: This was the technique I used to get all of those achievements.