# How do I get to the area near the end of the fridge?

Tags: borderlands-2

Trying to get the achievements for discovering all locations and there is one part near the end of the area I can't find anyway of getting to

Comment: It would be good if you show screenshot. Otherwise you can check what area you miss using [wiki](https://borderlands.fandom.com/wiki/The_Fridge) or maybe just going through waypoints in online map ([here](https://www.ign.com/maps/borderlands-2/thefridge) is one).

Comment: [Relevant](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/84873/135338).

Comment: I assume you meant to tag this with [tag:borderlands-2], since that area isn't in the first game.

Comment: @MBraedley, I didn't even noticed a wrong tag. If you play all borderlands you don't need numbers in tag, unless it's about something what is not unique ;)

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to do the mission [The Cold Shoulder](https://borderlands.fandom.com/wiki/The_Cold_Shoulder) (given by Scooter) in order to gain access to the Rat Maze. According to the wiki:

> Entry to the Rat Maze is barred on initial entry to the Fridge and
>   becomes accessible when pizza and flowers are placed for Laney White
>   in The Cold Shoulder.

[image]

Once you've gained access the the Rat Maze, you will be able to get to 
Crystal Claw Pit

> The Crystal Claw Pit is a large open area at the end of the Rat Maze.

[image]

and the Rakk Cave.

> This area is elevated well above the floor of Frigid Cleft near the
>   Outwash gate. It can be accessed by fighting through the Rat Maze...

[image]

Image sources: [1](http://orcz.com/Borderlands_2:_Rat_Maze), [2](http://orcz.com/Borderlands_2:_Crystal_Claw_Pit), [3](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiu2ePCxrfjAhVSL6wKHdnVDPAQjxx6BAgBEAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DeutCEFZ49rY&psig=AOvVaw3LuAjBaUbK0vDAa4v8tkNw&ust=1563301610028640).

Comment: These are the most likely areas you've missed, since the Rat Maze is initially locked.  The other named locations in the Fridge are freely accessible.